# Convert an image to black and white mask using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I have a transparent background image and i want to color all transparent region as black and rest of region as white.

```
imgage = cv2.imread("imgage.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
trans_mask = image[:,:,3] == 255
image[trans_mask] = [255, 255, 255, 255]
```

The output i got it. I got inside area to fill white and outside area to fill black. Any suggestion

[image]
Original input
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is starting out with a fully-black image and filling in just the area with positive alpha:

```
res = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], np.uint8) # black by default
colored_areas = image[...,3] > 0
res[colored_areas] = 255
```

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> i want to color all transparent region as black and rest of region as white.

So this should satisfy your request:

[image: the alpha channel]

and you get that from this simple code:

```py
image[:,:,3]
```

Just apply `imwrite` or `imshow`+`waitKey` (or matplotlib) to see the data.